# Installing Packages in PyCharm

Tags: package-management, python, pip, ide

I'm using Mint Cinnamon (very new) and tryign to get some packages in PyCharm. When I use the package installer for Numpy or Pandas I get the error message:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And if I try to upgrade pip in the terminal I get:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'download.py'
```

What steps should I take to get these packages into PyCharm. Project interpreter is '/usr/bin/python3.4

Comment: Have you tried installing the packages using sudo?

Comment: I successfully upgraded pip which allowed me to install Scipy and Numpy. When I try to install Pandas through PyCharm I get "pandas/lib.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: Now please try: `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

Comment: It look a little longer but still spit out this error message: `error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Comment: You could also try `python-dev` instead. These as well: `libxml2-dev` and `libxslt1-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I looked into it and found this answer from another post:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev

sudo easy_install greenlet

sudo easy_install gevent
```

Original post is :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/error-setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-wit